# Tabela não é formada corretamente utilizando 'appendChild'

Tags: javascript, table

Não está escrevendo todos os dados que deveriam virar (td), apenas um é registrado e os outros 2 ficam de fora

```js
function Gerar() {
    matrizAnimais = new Array;
    matrizAnimais = [
        ["A", "B", ""],
        ["", "", "G"],
        ["","H",""]
    ];

    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    var tr     = document.createElement('tr');
    var td     = document.createElement('td');
        for (linha = 0; linha < 3; linha++) {
            output.appendChild(tr);
            for (coluna = 0; coluna < 3; coluna++) {
                td.innerText = matrizAnimais[linha][coluna];
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
        }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="titulo">
        <h1>Caça-Palavras</h1>
        <form>
            <button type="button" onClick="Gerar()">Gerar Caça-Palavras</button>
            
            <table id="output">
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Entendi o erro!
Basicamente o que deveria ser feito é definição das variaveis relacionadas a criação do elemento (tr) e (td) estarem dentro da estrutura de repetição também.

Da seguinte forma:

```js
for (linha = 0; linha < 3; linha++) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr');
            output.appendChild(tr);
            for (coluna = 0; coluna < 3; coluna++) {
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                td.innerText = matrizAnimais[linha][coluna];
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
        }
```